# Characteritzation of $p$ for Rabin's test

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

The Rabin's test says that $f$ is an irreductible polynomial  over $\mathbb{F}_p$ if and only if

- $f\mid (x^{p^{n}}-x)$
- mcd$(f,x^{p^{n/q}}-x)=1$ $\forall q\mid n$

We are searching **conditions for $p$** that satisfies the Rabin's test for the specific case on a $3^{rd}$ degree irreductible polynomial. So, we are searching conditions for $p$ that:

- $f\mid (x^{p^{3}}-x)$
- gcd$(f,x^{p}-x)=1$

We found that for example, with $f(x)=x^3-x+1$ and $p\in \{3, 13, 29, 31, 41, 47, 71\}$, $f(x)$ is irreductible in $\mathbb{F}_p$. But we don't know if that $p$'s have a characteritzation.

Comment: Is there a question? What is it? Anyway, a cubic polynomial is irreducible over a field $K$ if and only if it has no zeros in $K$. In your case $K=\Bbb{F}_p$, so a cubic polynomial $f(x)\in\Bbb{F}_p[x]$ is irreducible if and only if $f(a)\neq0$ for $a=0,1,2,\ldots,p-1$. This is equivalent to the latter requirement $\gcd(f,x^p-x)=1$ (more convenient computationally, if $p$ is largish). To summarize: for cubics you don't need the general version of Rabin.

Comment: Re: the edit. Ok. Then it depends on the cubic. If its discriminant (in $\Bbb{Z}$) is a square, then we can find a modulus $m$ and a set of residue classes $S$ modulo $m$ such that $f$ is irreducible modulo $p$ if and only if $p\in S$. If the discriminant is not a square, then such a characterization is not possible (but there may be other ways using a suitable binary quadratic form). See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3255851/11619).

Comment: Okey! Thank you very much!!